# What episode or season does Oliver tell someone to “Go to hell” and then the person fires back “Can’t. Already here”

Tags: dc, episode-identification, arrowverse, arrow, green-arrow

I was just thinking about Oliver telling people to go to hell but someone says they are already there. Who is it?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you're thinking of [Adrian Chase](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5607512/characters/nm1854386) in ["Kapiushon"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5607512/characters/nm1854386), episode 17 of season 5?

> Adrian Chase : Cecil Adams. You know him by his street name, The Count.You put arrows in him.
>
> Oliver Queen : He was gonna kill a friend of mine.
>
> Adrian Chase : Felicity Smoak. Yeah.
>
> [puts on Oliver's quiver]
>
> Adrian Chase : Confess or you get the same 3 arrows.
>
> Oliver Queen : Go to hell.
>
> Adrian Chase : I've already been there, Oliver, and I've come back with a message for you.
>
> [fires 3 arrows at Oliver]

The scene in question:

Comment: This is so helpful thank you! But I might be thinking of something in the flash too. I can remember those exact words that I Said up there and I just can’t seem to remember if its flash or arrow

Comment: I don’t think this is the thing that I am thinking of. Can you think of any other times the arrow or flash said that??!!